# What is the integral of $1/(1+x)$

Tags: calculus

The integral of $1/(1+x)$ with respect to $x$ can either be $\arctan(\sqrt{x})$ or $\ln(1+x)$. Which one is it? Because I am sure these two functions are not the same.

Comment: Are you sure it can be $\arctan\sqrt x$?

Comment: did you try deriving both functions

Comment: What happens with the substitution $y=x+1$?

Comment: Have you tried plotting the difference of these two functions?

Comment: I just realized the error I made. My apology.

Answer (score 3):

Although the derivative of $\arctan(x)$ is $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$, the derivative of $\arctan(\sqrt{x})$ is not $\dfrac{1}{1+x}$. Using the chain rule we find that it is $\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}(1+x)}$. The derivative of $\ln(1+x)$ is $\dfrac{1}{1+x}$, so this is the correct antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln|1+x|$$
The derivative of $\arctan \sqrt x$ is 
$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt x^2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt x} = \frac{\sqrt x}{2x+2x^2}$